# After designing in "Blend for Visual Studio 2017", how can i code that UI ?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, blend

I recently installed the Visual Studio 2017. And i am new to this IDE and C# also. I saw that awesome GUI can create by Blend. But i don't have any idea how to link Visual Studio 2017 and Blend for Visual Studio. And my biggest problem is how to code that GUI (Design in Blend) ? like NetBeans ?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: We don't write tutorials here. Did you consider https://www.google.com/search?q=VS+Blend+tutorial&oq=VS+Blend+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.7478j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Also, when you created your account here it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so before asking your next question here.

Comment: Sry, i am new to Stackoverflow. Any way do you guys have any idea regarding this question ?